# How to replace uni code character in ssis package

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ssis, etl, flat-file

I am trying to load DAT file to sql server table .A particular column of DAT file having � in a particular column of the file .I am trying to replace this character using a expression in derived column transformation .
Following is the expression .

```
(DT_STR,1000,1252) REPLACE( [Comments] ,N'�','')
```

It is was throwing error ,expression is not getting evaluated .
Can anybody help me here .
Many thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're loading the physical file with the wrong encode. Are you, for example, trying to read a UTF-8 file but specifing in SSIS that it has a UTF-16 encode?

Comment: � is the replacement character for when an invalid sequence of code points is read. It's often just a visual placeholder and within SSIS probably not actually `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`, which would make it immune to your replacement call. If the encoding of the file is not just wrong, you may need to take a closer look at the bytes of the file with a hex viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try two approaches:

## (1) Changing the file encoding

As mentioned in the comments, `�` is a replacement of a invalid character in the selected encoding.

First, check that the column data type is `DT_WSTR` not `DT_STR`**

Also, try setting the encoding to `Unicode` or try using a encoding detection tool such as:

- [CHARSET DETECTOR – FREE ONLINE TEXT FILES CHARSET DETECTOR](http://www.mimastech.com/charset-detector-free-online-text-files-charset-detector/)
- [Using NotePad ++ to Detect Text File Encoding](https://www.litigationsupporttipofthenight.com/single-post/2016/09/27/Using-NotePad-to-Detect-Text-File-Encoding)
- [How to detect the encoding of a file?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file)
- [Super Encoding Detector](https://github.com/pommedeterresautee/SuperEncodingDetector)

**But i don't think until now there is a powerful encoding detection application or library where all encodings are supported**

To change the flat file connection manager encoding, you can check the Unicode checkbox or select a Code Page from the drop down  list:

[image]

## (2) Removing unwanted characters

If you don't have a problem with encodings and you know the right file encoding, if the file creation is not done correctly, these `�` characters have no meaning and **cannot be reverted**, you must check the file creation operation and check if there is a problem or difference between the data source encodings or collation and the flat file encoding.

Or you should remove these characters using a script component or derived column:

```
(DT_WSTR,1000)REPLACE([Comments] ,"�","")
```

*Note: Don't use `N` literal before the `�` mark and don't convert to `DT_STR` since it might be other unicode characters that cannot be converted.

**Additional information**

- [SSIS ETL: Handling Character Encodings and Conversions](https://benefic.net/ssis-character-encoding-conversions/)